# How do I append to a list deeply nested in a dict and keep the nested structure?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, dictionary

I am trying to append to a list buried in a deeply nested dict. However, whenever I try to append to the list it flattens the dict:

```
import copy

my_d = {'this': 'that'}
deeply_nested = {'and': {'another': {'string': {'separated': {'by': {'underscore': {'my_l': []}}}}}}}
print 'initial: ', deeply_nested

for i in range(10):
    for k, v in deeply_nested.iteritems():
        tmp = copy.deepcopy(v)
        while not isinstance(tmp, list):
            for v in tmp.values():
                 tmp = copy.deepcopy(v)
        tmp.append(my_d)
        deeply_nested[k] = copy.deepcopy(tmp)

print 'final: ', deeply_nested
```

Results:

```
initial:  {'and': {'another': {'string': {'separated': {'by': {'underscore': {'my_l': []}}}}}}}
final:  {'and': [{'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}]}
```

The final version is missing the nested keys and should be:

```
{'and': {'another': {'string': {'separated': {'by': {'underscore': {'my_l': [{'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}]}}}}}}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might have misunderstood how copy works. Because python has mutables, copy was implemented with the precise desire to avoid changing the original values.

Copy is intended to copy object/values as a new object, so you can act on a new object and **not** change the original one. By creating a copy of a list, you will never be able to append to the original list as you intended.

Instead traverse your dictionary to the list, and because list is a mutable object, change it directly. That change will be reflected on the dictionary.

```
import copy

my_d = {'this': 'that'}
deeply_nested = {'and': {'another': {'string': {'separated': {'by': {'underscore': {'my_l': []}}}}}}}
print 'initial: ', deeply_nested

for i in range(10):
    tmp = deeply_nested.values()[0]
    while not isinstance(tmp,list):
        tmp = tmp.values()[0] #this will reference the list in the dict, changes to tmp are changes to that list.
    tmp.append(my_d)

print 'final: ', deeply_nested
```

Which results in

```
initial:  {'and': {'another': {'string': {'separated': {'by': {'underscore': {'my_l': []}}}}}}}

final:  {'and': {'another': {'string': {'separated': {'by': {'underscore': {'my_l': [{'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}, {'this': 'that'}]}}}}}}}
```

As for why your program fails, just look at the steps you take:

1. k becomes `and`, v becomes `{'another': {'string': {'separated': {'by': {'underscore': {'my_l': []}}}}}}`
2. tmp copies v into a new object (all changes done to tmp will not reflect on v)
3. tmp traverses down the remaining dict as:

   ```
   {'another': {'string': {'separated': {'by': {'underscore': {'my_l': []}}}}}}
   {'string': {'separated': {'by': {'underscore': {'my_l': []}}}}}
   {'separated': {'by': {'underscore': {'my_l': []}}}}
   {'by': {'underscore': {'my_l': []}}}
   {'underscore': {'my_l': []}}
   {'my_l': []}
   []
   ```
4. You append to that last value, which is a copy of the actual list you want to change. Therefore the actual list will not change, only the tmp. tmp becomes `[{'this': 'that'}]`
5. You say `deeply_nested[k] = copy.deepcopy(tmp)`. From step 1. k=`any`. From step 4. tmp=`[{'this': 'that'}]`, therefore:

   ```
   {'and': [{'this': 'that'}]}
   ```

   Rinse and repeat 10 times to get what you got.

Comment: This solves the question but in trying to implement it I realized the problem is more complex...I'll post another question.